# Command line cURL to PHP conversions, where is documentation?

Tags: php, curl

I could not find good documentation anywhere which explain what each command line cURL switches such as `-s`, `-F`, etc correspond to in php cURL

Comment: http://php.net/curl   that wasn't too hard to find? Or maybe it was...

Comment: Not exactly, the solution points to this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php but on that documentation page I cant find what SETOPT functions should correspond to -F and -s switches. Is there a link that clearly explains which more clearly which php functions should be invoked for specific command line switches

Comment: @dr_k: You should outline specifics in your question, otherwise others might read your question different to what you wanted to ask about.

Comment: so look up the command line curl documentation, find that the F flag does, and then look for the equivalent CURLOPT

Comment: @dr_rk:  `-F` should correspond to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, and `-s` loosely translates to `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

Comment: For `-s` `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`

Comment: `-s` is by default, as for the progress bar you need to implement callbacks your own. similar with `-v`.